# How to access :hover pseudo class with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a CSS-class with a hover pseudo class:

```
.nav-collapse a:hover {
   background: #DEDEDE;
   border-radius: 3px;
}
```

I would like to dynamically change the background color with jQuery, i.e. access the CSS-class (.nav-collapse a:hover) and change the background color. I tried the following, which does not work:

```
$(".nav-collapse a:hover").css({
      "background": "#000",
      "color": "#fff",
});
```

What is the proper way to access the :hover class of a CSS-class?

Comment: `:hover` is a pseudo-class, not a pseudo-element. You're applying styles to the a element when it's hovered. It's not clear what you're trying to do here. Are you trying to change the styles of an a element that is being hovered during a scroll event?

Comment: Change the background color within the CSS class .nav-collapse a:hover

Comment: The event or use case is completely irrelevant here. The objective has been made pretty clear.

Comment: how do you hover while scrolling?  Can you explain or provide a little more about the scenario as maybe we're not understanding your issue?

Comment: @MiaSno it's possible by using the mousewheel to scroll or using the arrow keys to scroll

Comment: @Huangism I know that but I don't understand why and if so, that's a very simple solution.

Comment: @user3046831 The point we are trying to get across is you might have the wrong thinking/approach. I don't need to provide a solution to comment but thanks. There is already an answer anyway

Comment: @MiaSno No one knows because OP did not state it

Comment: @Huangism I'm asking OP to explain it further.

Comment: Fair enough - I misunderstood the core question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're simply asking how to modify an existing CSS rule that contains a dynamic pseudo-class, that is not possible by DOM interfacing with jQuery since jQuery deals with DOM elements, not CSS rules — you will need to modify the document stylesheet directly instead, which is often cumbersome. This applies to almost any dynamic pseudo-class, and not just `:hover`.

A much more elegant approach is to move the new style declarations to a separate CSS rule with a different class name for example, and apply that class to your element as desired. This decouples your style declarations from your script, eliminating the need to modify your styles from your script altogether. To wit:

```
.nav-collapse a:hover {
   background: #DEDEDE;
   border-radius: 3px;
}

.nav-collapse a.scrolling:hover {
   background: #000;
   color: #fff;
}
```

And:

```
$('.nav-collapse a').addClass('scrolling');
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how:

```js
 $(".nav-collapse > a").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).css({
          "background": "#000",
          "color": "#fff",
        });
 })

 $(".nav-collapse > a").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).css({
          "background": "",
          "color": "",
        });
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-collapse">
  <a href="#">link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Might as well add/remove class instead

Comment: @nicael Can you check this and suggests to me how can I achieve it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66923436/on-hover-after-element-move-to-current-div